# Terraform npm ci prior to zipping and deploying

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

This worked in the previous version of terraform, but since I updated to the current version 0.13.5, it stopped creating the node_modules folder prior to zipping when I do `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`. I need some help.

Terraform v0.13.5,

- provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/archive v2.0.0
- provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.15.0
- provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/null v3.0.0

```
resource "null_resource" "npm_install" {
  triggers = {
    lambda_hash = timestamp()
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "cd lambdas/my_lambda && npm ci"
  }
}

data "archive_file" "my_lambda_zip" {
  depends_on  = [null_resource.npm_install]
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${path.module}/lambdas/my_lambda/"
  output_path = "my_lambda.zip"
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that a `null_resource` applies during a `plan`. I would think this should work for an `apply`, but not a `plan`. I believe you can also defer the `data` source to only resolve during an `apply`, which would cause the state to fail to ever reach convergence, but it seems like you want this resource to apply every time anyway?

Comment: I have a trigger setup to check the hash of the folder, but in this sample I try it every time.

Comment: Your terraform snippet works fine for me. I only replaced the `npm ci` with `touch build-${timestamp} to simulate it. I'm also using tf 0.13.05. There must be something else going on, can you share more details?